# Symmetries of Geometrical Objects in Space

Tags: abstract-algebra

The symmetries of the platonic solids form groups of order 12, 24 and 60. My question is that, are these groups $A_4$ , $S_4$ and $A_5$ ? I also want to know any other object - regular or irregular with its group of symmetries Can anybody help plz

Comment: Yes to the first question. The next to last sentence makes no sense to me - every geometric object has some group of symmetries. Search the web for _polyhedral symmetry_.

Comment: @Ethan you r right every geometrical object has some group of symmetries and I wanted to know if there's an intresting group (non cyclic) corresponding to a known non regular object. Anyway I will search the web.

Comment: In the plane the $n$-gon has the dihedral group of symmetries. With that information you can find the groups for the pyramid and prism over an $n$-gon.

Comment: @EthanBolker: “every geometric object has some group of symmetries” — But if the object is sufficiently irregular, that group may be the trivial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every geometrical object has group of symmetries - trivial group if the object has no symmetry otherthan rotation by $0^0$. Let start from plan, the regular n-gons in the plan generate the famous dihedral groups $D_n$, but the irregular planer shapes also have symmetries - the alphabets A, B, K, D, U have one line symmetry, F & G don't have any while H has two lines if summaries. The cyclic groups $C_3$ and $C_12$ are the examples of the groups symmetries of Fan and Clock in space.